# Error in Laravel on live server [This page isn’t working HTTP ERROR 500 ]

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have moved my website from one server[go daddy] to another[webserver247] and now it is not working , I have tries everything but it seems nothing is working. It is working on my previous  server fine but I dont understand what is the issue on this server. I tried to re-write the htaccess but it didnt work either.

This is htaccess from public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

and this the htaccess on root folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

can anyone please help me,I would really appreciate it.
 Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check you have a `.env` file present. Moving servers there are so many things that it could be.

Comment: I did change the database name, username, password

Comment: Without accessing server logs, it's difficult to determine why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn `APP_DEBUG` to `TRUE` in your `.env` file. This should allow you to see the error being thrown so you can act on it. Unfortunately it is hard to simply debug a 500 error without knowing exactly what is being thrown.